# [42000][1044] Access denied for user 'bryce901'@'%' to database 'information_schema' on Intellij

Tags: java, database, intellij-idea

I've gone through a lot of other posts trying to find some answer to this and I have granted privileges to the user. I'm connecting to a Google Cloud Instance but keep getting the error "[42000][1044] Access denied for user 'bryce901'@'%' to database 'information_schema'"
The code I'm trying to run is

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'bryce901'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE TABLE Theemployeedatabase(
                      EmployeeID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      FirstName varchar(25),
                      LastName varchar(25),
                      StreetAddress VARCHAR(30)
)
```

Comment: Did you do `FLUSH USERS`?

Comment: @DroidX86 I used this
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';